# How to return records with total rows found in 1 function

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, npgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_function(_limit integer, _skip integer, _sortcolumn text, _sortasc boolean)
  RETURNS SETOF some_table AS
$BODY$

begin

 return query execute 'select * from some_table order by "'||_sortcolumn||'"' ||case when _sortasc then 'asc' else 'desc' end ||' limit $1 offset $2;' using _limit, _skip;

end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100
  ROWS 100;
```

i want to pass parameter by reference, so i can assign total rows to param. so far i find it impossible. any suggestion? i'm using C#

edit

i found 'RAISE NOTICE' probably useful. still find a way to recieve notice in .Net via npgsql

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do that. If you are calling this function directly using command object, the ExecuteScalar function returns the number of row returned by the command.

```
rowCountValue = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Or, you can do it the in the function definition;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_function(_limit integer, _skip integer, _sortcolumn text, _sortasc boolean, OUT _row_count integer)
  RETURNS SETOF some_table AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    _result RECORD;
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM some_table ORDER BY "'||_sortcolumn||'"' ||case when _sortasc then 'asc' else 'desc' end ||' limit $1 offset $2;' INTO _result using _limit, _skip;

GET DIAGNOSTICS _row_count = ROW_COUNT;

return result;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100
  ROWS 100;
```

If you query building is ok, then this one should work quite well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You may also give a try to change your function to return set of refcursors instead and return a resultset with you rows count and another set with your data.

Check out "Getting full results in a DataSet object: Using refcursors" section from Npgsql Users Manual: http://manual.npgsql.org There you'll find how to do that.

I hope it helps.